# Jest "encountered an unexpected token. Jest failed to parse a file" - VueJS + BabylonJS + Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I am setting up Jest in my project to write unit test cases. When I run npm test I am faced with an error. I have configured Babel but the error still pops up.

Here is the Babel and Jest config. I have added them in the `package.json` file:

```json
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "node",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]
    ]
  },
```

Here is the full error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
>
> Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
>
> export * from "./abstractScene.js";
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: May you provide more details about your issue e.g. full error log, package.json etc. From first view your jest config is correct